# SetText using Broadcast Intent android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i am able to display current time and a counter in my textviews but i want to                                               display uploaded and downloaded bytes in the same instead. below are my codes-

in other words, i want to send bandwidth usage to receiver class instead of sending current time and counter.

**broadcast service** (this calss sends data to receiver class)

```
    public class BroadcastService  extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");

        intent.putExtra("time", new Date().toLocaleString());
        intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);       
        super.onDestroy();
    }       
}
```

**Bandwidth Usage Example**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
    }

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);
            TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);
            long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
            long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
            TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }
     };
}
```

i have tried this but it just shows the package name in both of the textviews

```
public class BroadcastService  extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;
    private long mStartRX = 0;
    private long mStartTX = 0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
         mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
            mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
              long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;
            //  RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
              long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;
            //  TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes)); 

            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 10 seconds
        }
    };    

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");

        intent.putExtra("rxBytes", toString());
        intent.putExtra("txBytes", toString());
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);       
        super.onDestroy();
    }       
}
```